# Selec2 AJAX call not happening after initializing with new options after 'destroy'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I've ran into a problem where I need to change `<select>` from regular list to AJAX results using Select2 plugin. I manage to change options on `<select>`, but AJAX call never happens if I try to search. Here's my simplified code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').select2();
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var options = $('select').data('select2').options.options;

    console.log(options);

    options.ajax = {
      url: '/echo/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250
    };

    $('select').data(options);
    $('select').empty();
    $('select').select2('destroy');
    $('select').select2();

    console.log($('select').data('select2').options.options);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <select style="width: 100px;">
  <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  <button>Refresh</button>
</div>
```

Also tried a different approach by setting options directly to Select2, but with no luck:

```
$('select').empty();
$('select').select2('destroy');
$('select').select2(options);
```

In both cases, AJAX object in the options is present after refresh.
Any advice what should be changed to trigger AJAX call is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't re-init select2 with all of the previous instance options.

You need to do something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').select2();
  $('button').on('click', function() {    
    // extending incase there is some data-* options
    var options = Object.assign({}, $('select').dataset, {
      ajax: {
        url: '/echo/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250
      }
    });

    $('select').empty();
    $('select').select2('destroy');
    $('select').select2(options);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <select style="width: 100px;">
  <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  <button>Refresh</button>
</div>
```